# Its possible to have only one foreach in this code instead of two?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5, laravel-blade

I have a page to edit the form of each registration type of a conference. In this form, there is a table that shows the questions that exist for that conference and then the user can select in which registration types to include that specific question trough checkboxes.

The fields name and surname are always included so there are no checkboxs for that fields. But then for the other questions, the user can select in which registration types to include each question.

The code is working, the issue is that I have this code below 2 times on the same page:

```
@foreach($registration_type as $rtype)
   ...
@endforeach
```

Do you know if its possible to change the code so that there are not so many requests when this page is accessed?

**view**:

```
...
<tr>    
    <td>Email</td>
    <td>
        @foreach($registration_type as $rtype)
        <div class="form-check">
            <input autocomplete="off" class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="{{ $rtype->id }}" id="{{$rtype->id}}">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1"> {{$rtype->name}}
            </label>
        </div>
        @endforeach
    </td>
    <td>
        @foreach($registration_type as $rtype)
        <div class="form-check">
            <input autocomplete="off" class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="{{ $rtype->id }}" id="{{$rtype->id}}">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1"> for the registration type "{{$rtype->name}}"
            </label>
        </div>
        @endforeach
    </td>
</tr>

@foreach($question as $q)
<tr>
    <td>{{$q->question}}</td>
    <td>
        @foreach($registration_type as $rtype)
        <div class="form-check">
            <input autocomplete="off" class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="{{ $rtype->id }}" id="{{$rtype->id}}">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1"> {{$rtype->name}}
            </label>
        </div>
        @endforeach
    </td>
    <td>
        @foreach($registration_type as $rtype)
        <div class="form-check">
            <input autocomplete="off" class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="{{ $rtype->id }}" id="{{$rtype->id}}">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1">for the registration type "{{$rtype->name}}"
            </label>
        </div>
        @endforeach
    </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
...
```

**Controller**:

```
class QuestionController extends Controller 
{ 
    public function edit($id) 
    { 
        $conf = Conf::find($id); 
        $registrationType = RegistrationType::where('conf_id', $id)->get(); 
        $question = Question::where('conf_id', $id)->get();

        return view('questions.edit')->with('conf', $conf)->with('registration_type', $registrationType)->with('question', $question);
    }
}
```

Comment: Whats the problem? Code duplicity or the fact that same `@foreach(...)` is executed twice.

Comment: share controller and model for `$question` ? May be you nee do use `with('registration_type')` in `question` controller with relation

Comment: @C2486 I think registration type is unrelated in this case, but you may very well be on to something; we don't know how OP gets `$registration_type`...

Comment: what Laravel version is this for?

Comment: Is for laravel 5.5.

Comment: Event::listen('iluminate.query', function($sql){
    var_dump($sql);
});
 dont show nothing on the page.

Comment: @JohnZ that video I linked you is for previous versions of Laravel so syntax may have changed (video was published **NOV. 12TH 2013**), use debugbar package for getting info about queries instead, video is about the main idea of **n+1** problem, and how to avoid it. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are bothered by code duplicity you can "export" the code to its own view and pass the parameters in `@include('view', ['param' => 'value'])`

**registration-type.blade.php**

```
@foreach($types as $type)
    <div class="form-check">
        <input autocomplete="off" class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="{{ $type->id }}" id="{{ $type->id }}">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1">for the registration type "{{ $type->name }}"
        </label>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

And use it within your view

```
@include('registration-type', ['types' => $registration_type])
```

---

Of course now you will have two `@include` statements so duplicity is not taken care of, but it looks nicer.

Comment: Thanks, but so in terms of code performance that approach is the same right? But the two "for each" in the same page are really needed?

Comment: @JohnZ Views are cached, what you gain using approach above is that if you need to modify the inners of `foreach` you do it only once - inside the *registration-type.blade.php*. Worry not about performance of `foreach` statements that just loop, look out for **n+1** problems instead (eg. using `->get()` on model within `foreach` block.

Comment: Thanks I didn't understand that ->get() on model within foreach block, can you explain better the performance issue?

Comment: @JohnZ free resource on the topic https://laracasts.com/lessons/eager-loading (also @C2486 in his comments is trying to identify how you get the `$registration_type` and also wants to eliminate n+1 if there is one). Watch the video and come back if you still do not understand.

Comment: class QuestionController extends Controller
{
    public function edit($id)
    {
        $conf = Conf::find($id);
        $registrationType = RegistrationType::where('conf_id', $id)->get();
        $question = Question::where('conf_id', $id)->get();


        return view('questions.edit')
            ->with('conf', $conf)
            ->with('registration_type', $registrationType)
            ->with('question', $question);
    }

Comment: Thanks, the  $registration_type come from the QuestionController.